# How do I pass a javascript variable through a URL?

Tags: javascript, php

I've recently learned 2 simple functions...
I'm passing includes via php with links such as:

```
a href="portfolio.php&content=picture-one"
```

I'm using js to cycle between items I have hidden on the page using:

```
function resumeText(text) 
{
    document.getElementById('resume-target').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById(text).innerHTML;
}
```

Both are working just fine. But now I'm trying to have a bit of fun with this and wondered if there is a way to 'merge' the two? I don't want to build the resume page out as a bunch of includes but thought it'd be nice on the site map (or for other links) to be able to jump to one of the 'text' values first instead of the one that loads by default

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I completely understand your question. If you want a "URL parameter" that's accessible via javascript, check out `window.location.hash`. You could then append `#section1`, `#section2`, etc. to your URL and have your javascript select content accordingly.

#### Choosing a section based on a `GET` variable

An easy way to choose a section based on `$_GET['content']` is to just have PHP output some javascript. In the `<head>` section of your HTML, you could do this:

```
<script>
var section = '<?php
if($_GET['content'] == "picture-one") {
    echo 'section-1'; // the ID of the section to show
}

else {
    echo 'section-2';
}
?>'
</script>
```

Then, you can call `resumeText(section);` and it will show the section ID that was stored in that variable based on the contents of `$_GET['content']`.

Comment: I just looked up the window.location.hash and I see what you mean - I think I did leave out some key information. I have used the hash to add anchors to pages so if

Comment: (EDIT: Didn't finish my edit to the above in time)
I just looked up the window.location.hash and I see what you mean - I think I did leave out some key information. 

In this case I have 4 items on my page:
- The target div and it's default content (in this case some about content)
- The 3 alternate divs that can be called to the target div (like skills, experience, works)

When going to the resume, it defaults to the 'about' section and I was just wondering if there was a way to direct the user to the resume.php page but have the kills section or example load immediately vs the about page?

Comment: Yep, you can definitely do that. How do you want the script to determine which section to show?

Comment: Never actually tried it so I'm open to recommendations. If it helps though I will roll whatever I end up with into a second use:

I have a portfolio section where the thumbnails link to a php include such as:
a href="portfolio.php&art=picture-1"
but the accordion menu that accompanies it is broken into subcategories and if "picture-1" is in "illustrations" I want to tell the accordion to start with the illustrations area open

Comment: So basically you want the `GET` variable to select the section? I added some code in my answer.